# Loading a video from gallery

Tags: codenameone

When I load a video from gallery in Codename One, there is a progressing slider in which it’s written “compressing video”. It’s on iOS only. Is it a default behavior of Codename One or a default behavior of iOS?

Comment: I don't think we show that. I think it's iOS manipulating the native video storage.